# Semantic Field (Hyponym/Hyperonym) for movies, books, tv shows, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently reorganizing my Pinterest account. I'm combining and separating boards to more efficiently sort my pins. I want to have a group of boards that will include movies, books, and tv shows. However, I would like the title of the group to be only one or two words. An example of how it is currently titled (with "Movies/Books" being the group title):

Movies/Books – Fault in Our Stars

Movies/Books – Hunger Games

Movies/Books – Lord of the Rings

Movies/Books – Star Wars

Movies/Books – Spongebob

Movies/Books – Star vs. Forces of Evil

Movies/Books – Star Trek

What I'm looking for is to replace the "Movie/Books" part of the title, so as to describe the overall grouping a little easier. (as a side note: I use the same title before the "Fault in our stars" and such so that when the pins are shown in alphabetical order, they are all together as "Movies/Books" will always start with the letter M).

Comment: I like Media (and have upvoted) but depending on the impression you wish to convey, **stories** and it's synonyms may work. I quite like **narratives**. Another possibility might even be **worlds**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply label the group as *titles*.

**title:**

a :  the distinguishing name of a written, printed, or filmed production

b :  a similar distinguishing name of a musical composition or a work of art

source: Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 1):

**[Media](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/media):**

> 2 plural form of **[medium](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/medium)**

**[Medium](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/medium)**:

> 1.1 A means by which something is communicated or expressed.

Comment: OP is not looking for the ***means*** by which something is communicated but the name of a particular grouping of ***productions***.

Answer (score 0):

***Franchise*** is what I would suggest.

> **franchise**:  1f orig. U.S. *A general title, format, or unifying concept
>   used for creating or marketing a series of products (esp. films,
>   television shows, etc.)*.

[from OED (sign-in needed to follow link)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74173?rskey=QV6kNl&result=1#eid)

I think this is better than "Titles" because it includes the concept of the continuing nature of the series and the multi-format nature of the group.  I think it works better than "Media" because in that group I would expect the entries to be "books", "internet", "Facebook", "newspapers", etc rather than actual productions like Star Wars, etc.

e.g.

> 1936   N.Y. Times 9 July 17/2 (heading)    Warner Brothers hold their
>   G-Man franchise with ‘Public Enemy's Wife’ at the Strand.
>
> 1986   L. Nimoy in Los Angeles Times 14 June 6   I think the studio
>   [is]..definitely interested in the future of the ‘Star Trek’
>   franchise.
>
> 1988   N.Y. Times 29 Sept. c21/1   Paramount had what the industry
>   calls ‘franchises’—strong movie series with built-in sequels—including
>   ‘Indiana Jones’, ‘Friday the 13th’ and ‘Star Trek’.
>
> 1998   Daily News of Los Angeles (Nexis) 8 Nov.   Wolf wanted to
>   produce something that was more of an extension of his ‘Law & Order’
>   franchise.
>
> 2005   FHM Jan. 163/1   Not only was The Getaway a rip-roaring
>   rocket-fuelled orgy of shooters, motors and Lahndon-based criminals,
>   it also happened to be the UK's best-selling new game franchise ever.